# Can you convert secret GitHub gists to public?

Tags: github

Is it possible to convert a secret GitHub gist into a public viewable version?

It seems like this is something that would appear under "Advanced Options", unfortunately there is no option to convert a gist to public, as far as I can tell.

[image: advance options for a gist]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[You can](https://github.com/blog/1837-change-the-visibility-of-your-gists), starting from May 9th, 2014.

Just click on "Edit Gist", there will be an option to change it private or public near delete button on the left of "delete gist" menu.

[image]